# Error in last update for sane in Ubuntu 18.04? (Canon MG5750)

Tags: 18.04, scanner, canon

Because my [*Canon MG5750*](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg5750.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=LINUX) is not supported by `sane`, I installed the *Canon* driver myself.

Using this driver (`scangearmp2`) all is well. I can scan in black or in color.
But using `sane` it is impossible to get the colors correctly. As I have a former scan in color in an archive, I suspect that there is a problem in the latest update of `sane`.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.